# new DAG doesn't catch up to a missed schedule (schedule_interval is a cron)

Tags: airflow

I have an Airflow DAG that previously did not have a schedule. It is turned on in the Airflow interface and I was running it manually. Just now, I updated the schedule as follows:

```
[in the default arguments object that is fed into the DAG]
'catchup': True
'start_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 1)

[in my DAG object instantiation]
schedule_interval='0 0 17 * *'
```

Right now it is August 18, 2020 in UTC. I expected that this would cause the DAG to immediately run once the code changes were added, but so far it isn't running.

I have said that the schedule starts on August 1 2020, and the schedule interval means "every month on the 17th," so by that definition it has missed a run at midnight on August 17th. Why isn't it catching up that past run, since `catchup` is set to `True`? When will it first run?

I know that there is some controversy surrounding the confusing behavior of `schedule_interval`, because the first run is after the first interval after start_date. However, even those discussions, which I have read, have to do with the case when `schedule_interval` is an actual interval like `@daily`, and when somebody has placed the first run in the future. I cannot find any documentation for what should happen for catchup when the new schedule starts in the past and/or when `schedule_interval` is a cron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set your `start_date` to be one "interval" of your `schedule_interval` *behind* the current date/time; where "interval" is the amount of time between subsequent executions.

The easiest way to do this is to just set `start_date` to be the date of when it would have ran prior to the date you want it to run, if it were already installed and running. In this instance it would be `datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 17)`